# Directory and filname get stripped to 8 characters after Mounting an ISO created by JIIC

Tags: java, iso9660

I have created an ISO using JIIC. When I open the ISO content through 7z in windows machine I see all contents are proper. But if I mount the ISO in Solaris machine I see that the directories and filename is trimmed to 8 and 8+3 chanracter. I use the following option to in maven section to create ISO.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.stephenc.java-iso-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>iso9660-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-iso</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>iso</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.build.finalName}.iso</finalName>
                            <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/iso</inputDirectory>

                            <volumeId>${product}</volumeId>
                            <enableRockRidge>false</enableRockRidge>
                            <enableJoliet>true</enableJoliet>
                            <restrictDirDepthTo8>false</restrictDirDepthTo8>
                            <interchangeLevel>2</interchangeLevel>
                            <padEnd>false</padEnd>
                            <forceDotDelimiter>false</forceDotDelimiter>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Can you please help me here. Also I see that file name changes to small letter while mounting the ISO.